# Best performance when querying tree structure with EF4.1

Tags: performance, tree, entity-framework-4.1, traversal

This most be a very common question, but I cant find a good answer too it on google.

I have a standard tree structure,

- Id
- ParentId
- Name
- ForeignKeyId

My first attempt at a query

```
    return db.Tree
        .Where(t => t.ForeignKeyId == xxx && t.Parent == null).SingleOrDefault();
```

This will result in a N*2 select to database. Very slow for pretty small trees, time outs for big trees.

Is there any good way to speed up tree traversing with EF4.1?

edit: this one works a little better

```
    var eager = db.Tree.Include(t => t.Children).Where(t => t.ForeignKeyIdd == xxx).ToList();

    return eager
        .Where(t.Parent == null).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return db.Tree
        .Where(t => t.ForeignKeyId == xxx && t.ParentId == null)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```